# Excel - Changing all formulas based on row number

Tags: excel, formula, relation

Goodmorning!

I would love to to keep it simple. 
I have some numbers where I have to make a monthly report from.

For example the numbers I would take in the monthly report, are now based in:

```
=K54
=N54
=L54
=O54
=M54
```

Next month the same type of numbers are based in:

```
=K55
=N55
=L55
=O55
=M55
```

So just 1 row under. 
Is it possible to change all simple formulas at once?

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a PivotTable to create the monthly report, and just filtering on the Month column to show data for the current month. Do you have a 'Month' column or similar?

Comment: Very little information, aside from Olly's approach below there is a fromula called "=row()" which returns row numbers, upon which you establish a logical flow, there are quite a few possible way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your range of formulas.

Click `Home > Editing > Find & Select > Replace...`

Replace what: 54

Replace with: 55

Click `Replace All`

Comment: Would probably be safer as a VBA to limit the Find & Replace range only to a single relevant column. But still upvoted for practicality.

Comment: Sure. Sounds like it would be better to rewrite the Monthly report to be parameter driven, rather than relying on cell references... but we work with what's asked, and this is quick and simple ;-)